# Simplest way for users to add themselves to a "team" in Django

Tags: python, django, one-to-many, models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models 

class Team(models.Model):
   team_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True) ## they can create a new team here
   description = models.TextField()
   slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True) ## I connect my User here, so they can "own" this info...
```

---

Users have the option to create a new team (via the 'team_name' field), but I also want to give users the option to join another team (created by a different user), can I just add a new field to my Team model? And preferably, on the form, they could see a list of created teams, check the one they want to join and save the form.

Could I add something like this to my Team class:

```
    team = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Team.objects.all()).filter('team_name')
```

or maybe something like:

```
TEAM_CHOICES = Team.objects.all()).filter('team_name')
team = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=TEAM_CHOICES))
```

And, how would that data be saved correctly?

Comment: `OneToOneField`? Your team can only have one user?

Comment: @burhan - yeah that should probably be a ManyToMany?

Comment: @MichaelSebastian you either need to make the `OneToOneField` a `ManyToManyField` or put a `ForiegnKey` to `Team` on your user. Personally, I'd take a FK over a M2M every time. But if you take an M2M instead of a FK on the `User` model, you need to consider how to store the user who created the team.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to allow users to join a team, I'd have a team attribute on the user model that was a FK to the Team.

Then in a form, you could define the list of available teams as you've suggested;

```
team = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Team.objects.all())
```

And I'd also suggest looking at [Select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2) which creates a javascript 'search' type field that will filter the teams when someone starts to type characters.

Furthermore, the `user` field in your `Team` model would be better named as `creator` or `owner` so that you don't confuse them with a standard user associated with the team.

Comment: @MichaelSebastian are you importing the class from your models in your forms module? You'll need to have `from .models import Team` in order for Django to know what table it needs to query.

Comment: ah right - sorry - I misread what you said, I thought you said to add it to my models.py class

Comment: @MichaelSebastian no, you need that in the form for the user to pick a team. Then if you've chosen to put a Team ForeignKey on the user you can then set in your view the team on the User model to the team that's posted in the form.

Comment: so I added this to my user model: team = models.ForeignKey('Team'). I added this to my form: name = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Team.objects.values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()). But, when I try and save a team value, it says "team 1 is not a valid value for a primary key".

Comment: Yeah that's because the values for the drop down field will be the team names. It needs that to be the ID of the team objects in order to create the link to the object. Just do `queryset=Team.objects.all()` and it'll provide a list of the teams for you with the team IDs as the value for the select box.

Comment: So, I added that in, but now the output of the select list form says: "Team object, team object, team Object" (i currently have 3 teams)

Comment: @MichaelSebastian you need to define what the model should be called when represented as a string. For this it'll need a `def __str__(self): return self.name` type function. Read the docs on these methods; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#other-model-instance-methods